# How to parse multiple inputs into a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

What follows is a homework assignment that I have been stumped on all day and my code. I may be trying to go about this in the wrong way.. Would you guys tell me what I am doing wrong?

(1) Prompt the user for a title for data. Output the title. (1 pt)

```
Ex:
Enter a title for the data:

Number of Novels Authored

You entered: Number of Novels Authored
```

(2) Prompt the user for the headers of two columns of a table. Output the column headers. (1 pt)

```
Ex:
Enter the column 1 header:

Author name

You entered: Author name

Enter the column 2 header:

Number of novels

You entered: Number of novels
```

(3) Prompt the user for data points. Data points must be in this format: string, int. Store the information before the comma into a string variable and the information after the comma into an integer. The user will enter -1 when they have finished entering data points. Output the data points. Store the string components of the data points in a list of strings. Store the integer components of the data points in a list of integers. (4 pts)

```
Ex:
Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):

Jane Austen, 6

Data string: Jane Austen

Data integer: 6
```

(4) Perform error checking for the data point entries. If any of the following errors occurs, output the appropriate error message and prompt again for a valid data point.
•   If entry has no comma
•   Output: Error: No comma in string. (1 pt)
•   If entry has more than one comma
•   Output: Error: Too many commas in input. (1 pt)
•   If entry after the comma is not an integer
•   Output: Error: Comma not followed by an integer. (2 pts)

```
Ex:
Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):

Ernest Hemingway 9

Error: No comma in string.

Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):

Ernest, Hemingway, 9

Error: Too many commas in input.

Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):

Ernest Hemingway, nine

Error: Comma not followed by an integer.

Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):

Ernest Hemingway, 9

Data string: Ernest Hemingway

Data integer: 9
```

(4) Output the information in a formatted table. The title is right justified with a minimum field width value of 33. Column 1 has a minimum field width value of 20. Column 2 has a minimum field width value of 23. (3 pts)

```
Ex:
        Number of Novels Authored
Author name         |       Number of novels
--------------------------------------------
Jane Austen         |                      6
Charles Dickens     |                     20
Ernest Hemingway    |                      9
Jack Kerouac        |                     22
F. Scott Fitzgerald |                      8
Mary Shelley        |                      7
Charlotte Bronte    |                      5
Mark Twain          |                     11
Agatha Christie     |                     73
Ian Flemming        |                     14
J.K. Rowling        |                     14
Stephen King        |                     54
Oscar Wilde         |                      1
```

(5) Output the information as a formatted histogram. Each name is right justified with a minimum field width value of 20. (4 pts)

```
Ex:
         Jane Austen ******
     Charles Dickens ********************
    Ernest Hemingway *********
        Jack Kerouac **********************
 F. Scott Fitzgerald ********
        Mary Shelley *******
    Charlotte Bronte *****
          Mark Twain ***********
     Agatha Christie *************************************************************************
        Ian Flemming **************
        J.K. Rowling **************
        Stephen King ******************************************************
         Oscar Wilde *
```

My attempt is as follows: The commented out sections are things I have tried or have been trying.

```
title = input("Enter a title for the data:\n")

print('You entered:',title)

col1 = input("\nEnter the column 1 header:\n")

print('You entered:',col1)

col2 = input("\nEnter the column 2 header:\n")

print('You entered:',col2)

datapoint = input("\nEnter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n")


while datapoint != '-1':
    if datapoint == '-1':
        break
    my_dict = {}
    if ',' not in datapoint:
        #hasComma = False
        print('Error: No comma in string.\n')
        datapoint = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n")
    else:
        #hasComma = True
        split = datapoint.split(',')
        first = split[0].strip()
        second = split[1].strip()

        my_dict[first] = second

    #while hasComma == False:
     #   print('Error: No comma in string.\n')
     #   datapoint = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n")

    #while hasComma == True:
    #    split = datapoint.split(',')
    #    first = split[0].strip()
    #    second = split[1].strip()

    #    my_dict[first] = second
    print("Data string:",first)
    print("Data integer:",second)
    break
#print("Data string:",first)
#print("Data integer:",second)
```

I understand my code is very sloppy, I am new to this. As it is right now, I am getting 6/17 correct. So the first three parts of the assignment are working but everything after that is incomplete. I need help fixing my loops so that I can read consecutive inputs and error check each input. Once those work properly I should be able to figure out the table and histogram on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a valid input, your program will only collect a single response from the user. You have this initial `input()` call *outside* the loop:

```
datapoint = input("\nEnter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n")
```

But then, if it's a valid input, your loop exits, and you won't gather any additional input. Instead, move that call inside your loop:

```
while True:
    datapoint = input("\nEnter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n")
    if datapoint == '-1':
        break
```

This way, for ever iteration of the loop, the user will be prompted for an input. When the users enters '-1', it will break out of the look and the program will end.

`while True` is shorthand for "do this loop forever." By adding the `break` dependent on the value of `datapoint`, you can collect data indefinitely, but still stop based on a condition (the user entering '-1').

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!I knew it had to be something small like that. I suppose with practice I will catch/not make those mistakes easier.

Comment: You absolutely will; that's how it goes :)